# How to insert data into Influxdb from CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, excel, influxdb

I wanted to insert data from a CSV file to Influxdb. I have tried the below Python script. It was successful, but I want it to be inserted at particular time (I have a column in which date is specified).

```
import pandas as pd
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

client = InfluxDBClient(host='localhost', port=8086)
client.switch_database('databse_name')

file_path = r'file_name.csv'

csvReader = pd.read_csv(file_path)

print(csvReader.shape)
print(csvReader.columns)

for row_index, row in csvReader.iterrows() : 
    tags = row[1]
    #fieldvalue = row[2]
    json_body = [
        {
            "measurement": "Measurement_name",
            "tags": {
                        "Tag_name1": tags
                    },
            "fields": {
                        "Field1": row[2],
                        "Field2": row[3], 
                        "Field3": row[4]
                        }
        }
    ]
    client.write_points(json_body)
```

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `time` in the json_body:

```
json_body = [{
    "time": "<datetime, e.g. 2020-05-02T17:30:45Z>",
    "measurement": "Measurement_name",
    "tags": {
        "Tag_name1": tags
    },
    "fields": {
        "Field1": row[2],
        "Field2": row[3],
        "Field3": row[4]
    }
}]
```